# In dplyr::mutate, how to select a particular row?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I want to mutate a data frame (grouped) and create a new variable that has the value of a column for a particular row (within the group). Let us see an example:

```
df=data.frame(a=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=4),b=rep(c(1,2,3,4),3),v=1:12)
```

which gives me the data frame 

   `a b  v
1  a 1  1
2  a 2  2
3  a 3  3
4  a 4  4
5  b 1  5
6  b 2  6
7  b 3  7
8  b 4  8
9  c 1  9
10 c 2 10
11 c 3 11
12 c 4 12`

I want to create a new column (grouped by `a`) with the value of `v` when `b==4`

With plyr I would  do (somewhat inelegantly)

```
plyr::ddply(df, ~a, function(x) cbind(x,z=x[x$b==4,]$v))
```

which gives me what I want:

   `a b  v  z
1  a 1  1  4
2  a 2  2  4
3  a 3  3  4
4  a 4  4  4
5  b 1  5  8
6  b 2  6  8
7  b 3  7  8
8  b 4  8  8
9  c 1  9 12
10 c 2 10 12
11 c 3 11 12
12 c 4 12 12`

With `dplyr` I want something like

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(z=.[.$b==4,"v"])
```

which gives me

```
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
Groups: a [3]

       a     b     v        z
   (chr) (dbl) (int)    (chr)
1      a     1     1 <int[3]>
2      a     2     2 <int[3]>
3      a     3     3 <int[3]>
4      a     4     4 <int[3]>
5      b     1     5 <int[3]>
6      b     2     6 <int[3]>
7      b     3     7 <int[3]>
8      b     4     8 <int[3]>
9      c     1     9 <int[3]>
10     c     2    10 <int[3]> 
11     c     3    11 <int[3]>
12     c     4    12 <int[3]>
```

where the `z` column is

Source: local data frame [3 x 12]

```
     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
1     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4
2     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
3    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12    12
```

I also tried combinations of `filter` `{ }` and `merge` but so far no solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need `.$b`, just directly use `b==4` (assuming that there is only a single 4 in 'b' for each group in 'a'

```
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>% 
    mutate(z = v[b==4])
#       a     b     v     z
#   <fctr> <dbl> <int> <int>
#1       a     1     1     4
#2       a     2     2     4
#3       a     3     3     4
#4       a     4     4     4
#5       b     1     5     8
#6       b     2     6     8
#7       b     3     7     8
#8       b     4     8     8
#9       c     1     9    12
#10      c     2    10    12
#11      c     3    11    12
#12      c     4    12    12
```

If we have already loaded `plyr` library, it may be better to use

```
 dplyr::mutate(z = v[b==4])
```

as the `mutate` from `dplyr` can get masked from `mutate` in `plyr`

---

Using `dplyr_0.5.0`, the code in the OP's post gives me error

```
df %>%
   group_by(a) %>% 
   mutate(z=.[.$b==4,"v"])
#Error: not compatible with STRSXP
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using dplyr_0.4.3